# SQL server 2000: Need production optimized query to return each row count and size for each database in an instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want production optimized query to return each row count and size for each database table in an instance

Like:
DATABASE/CATALOG_NAME   TABLE_NAME  RECORD_COUNT SIZE(Bytes/KB/MB)

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far please, you need to show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL Server are you using?

SSMS has a built in report that will just do that.  You can export the report to excel.

What is better than that?

Check out this post from Buck Woody.  If you get to see him talk, please go.  Here is a very good presenter.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2007/12/14/sql-server-management-studio-standard-reports-disk-usage-by-table-top-tables.aspx

Comment: I have mentioned version as 2000. Also the bucky links is not working.

Comment: I have mentioned version as 2000. Also the bucky links is not working.Thanks

Comment: Jeff Moden is another SQL Server MVP - Check out his solution here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186967/sql-server-2000-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-tables-and-the-row-counts

Comment: I have tried suggested comments on this post but it always shows data from only one custom database. I don't know why there is no data present in 'sysobjects' table for other custom database. Is there any way we can see data for other custom database?

Comment: Jeff Modens script runs in the currently selected database.  Execute the USE statement to select a database of your choosing.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx